# std::vector push_back() crashes the program

Tags: c++, std, sfml, stdvector

I have a function that checks for other players' movement on the map and adjusts their position accordingly and it also checks that if the player just entered.

```
void mapManager::checkForOtherPlayerMovement(int plyId)
{
    sf::Packet receivedPacket;
    std::vector<player>::iterator it;
    player pl(0,0,1);

    if(socket->Receive(receivedPacket) == sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        int header;
        receivedPacket >> header;

        switch(header)
        {
            case PACKET_PLAYER_DISPATCHNEWPOSITION:
            {
                receivedPacket >> pl;

                std::cout << pl.plyId << std::endl;

                if(plyId != pl.plyId)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(pl.plyId != 0)
                        {
                            std::cout << "DEBUG1" << std::endl;
                            players->at(pl.plyId-1).posX = pl.posX;
                            players->at(pl.plyId-1).posY = pl.posY;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::cout << "DEBUG2" << std::endl;
                            players->at(pl.plyId).posX = pl.posX;
                            players->at(pl.plyId).posY = pl.posY;
                        }


                    }
                    catch(const std::out_of_range& oor)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Added new player!" << std::endl;
                        players->push_back(pl); // This crashes

                    }
                }


                break;

            }
            case PACKET_PLAYER_DISPATCHENTEREDMAP:
            {
                break;
            }


        }
    }





}
```

So basically the crash happens when a new player connects to the server and the game needs to add it inside the vector. Strange thing is that it didn't crash on visual studio 2010, but crashes when I changed to vs 2012 so I must be doing something wrong.

EDIT: Here is how the players vector is created

mapManager.h

```
std::vector<player> * players;
```

mapManager.cpp

```
players = new std::vector<player>();
```

Here I use the players vector

```
void mapManager::drawOtherPlayers(int plyId, player *ownPlayer)
{
    ownPlayerSprite->SetPosition(ownPlayer->getX(), ownPlayer->getY());
    window.Draw(*ownPlayerSprite);

    for(std::vector<player>::iterator it = players->begin(); it != players->end(); ++it) 
    {
            spriteToDraw->SetPosition(it->posX,it->posY);
            window.Draw(*spriteToDraw);
    }

}
```

My player class: [Player.h and player.cpp](http://pastebin.com/LJhQdFpL)

Comment: std::vector<player> * players;
players = new std::vector<player>();

Comment: What is the error you are getting when the program crashes?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x012E3146 in Game2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x30693BB8.

Comment: I got that from the way you use it ;) The reason I was asking about it, is that it seems to have been corrupted, so you'll have to check any access to it using a debugger and/or memory profiler to figure out if that's the case, and how to fix it.

Comment: Is the error consistent (does it happen every time)?

Comment: The only other place where the vector is accessed is the drawOtherPlayers where it just iterates through it and draws the sprites accordingly.

Comment: @asafrob Yes, it happens every time I try to connect another player.

Comment: Just want to say: I seriously doubt that it's `vector::push_back()` causing the crash.

Comment: Don't just check intended accesses. Check all accesses to the underlying memory structure. That's where a debugger and/or memory profiler comes in handy.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating the vector?

Comment: @phresnel It seems to be because I commented it out now and tried again, it doesn't crash without the push_back()

Comment: @JamesKanze Well I tried that if it would somehow fix the problem but it didn't so I just left it here, I can change it back to normal though.

Comment: I think it's a thread safety issue. Try to protect all accesses to the vector
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c9ceah3b.aspx

Comment: Also, what do you use `it` for?  Either it's an unused variable, or you're not showing all of the code.  If it is used: you are aware that `push_back` can invalidate all iterators into the vector, I hope.

Comment: It's pretty strange that it worked fine when compiled with vs 2010

Comment: @JamesKanze I edited the post and showed where I use it.

Comment: I just switched back to vs 2010 for this project and it works perfectly, can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be anything wrong with the code you've presented.

While the `try-catch` construct you're using might not be something I would do, there is nothing wrong with it as far as I can tell.  The C++03 and C++11 Standards both guarantee that `at` will `throw` an `std::out_of_range` if the element does not exist.

You need to look elsewhere for the bug.  One thing that piques my interest is the fact that you are dynamically allocating the `vector`.  No reasoning for this is presented, but since there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with how you're using the `vector` *assuming it exists*, a likely scenario is that the `vector` is corrupted, was deleted, or something else is wrong with your dynamic memory management.  If you can get by without using dynamic allocation, I would strongly recommend it.  If you can't get by without dynamic allocation, then at least use a smart pointer instead of raw pointers.

Another place to look is the constructors for `player`, in particular the copy constructor.  Since `push_back` is going to create a copy of the element being added, if there's nothing wrong with the `vector` itself, the problem might be in the copy constructor.

Write a copy constructor for `player`, like this:

```
player (const player& rhs)
:
  posX (rhs.posX),
  mapId (rhs.mapId),
  plyId (rhs.plyId),
  playerModel (rhs.playerModel)
{
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the first line of the initialization list.  Does it hit?  Step in to each member's constructor.  Do they crash?

Comment: I changed the dynamically allocated vector back to normal but the problem still persists.

Comment: @SamuliLehtonen:  In the same place and in the same way?

Comment: Yes at the same place. If I comment out the push back, it doesn't crash, so that's the line where it crashes.

Comment: @SamuliLehtonen:  That might be the line where it crashes, but you need to cast a wider net.  Just because it crashes there doesn't mean the problem is with the `push_back`.  Set a breakpoint on the `push_back` and step in to it.  Set a breakpoint on your copy constructor and step in to it as well.

Comment: I don't have special copy constructor for the player

Comment: @SamuliLehtonen:  Yes, you do.  If you didn't write one, the compiler wrote one for you.  `player`'s members still get copied.  The problem might be in one of those copies.  For debugging, write a copy constructor so that you can break on that.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I stepped into the push_back() and there it crashes on the line 1116 of vector file

reference at(size_type _Pos)
  { // subscript mutable sequence with checking
  if (size() <= _Pos)
   _Xran();
  return (*(this->_Myfirst + _Pos));
  }

Comment: I added the player.h and player.cpp to the main post

Comment: I virtually bet there is the problem.

Comment: Well I added breakpoints in the copy constructor and they don't even seem to hit for some reason.